# Duplicate page issues in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

**My WordPress web site has multiple versions. **

I have set the **WordPress Address (URL)** to https://domainname, also **Site Address(URL)** is set to https://domainname. I want only the **non www** versions (https://domainname) to appear in the URL, as the indexing and other SEO properties have been set to this, and it was working this way for the last 2 years. However recently I had to **restore** my site (as directed by GoDaddy customer support) due to some issue and now the https://www versions are are available and accessible.

If I change the redirect settings in .htaccess file to redirect from www versions to non-www versions a lot of site features like CSS styling, favicons breaks. So I have not implemented this.

Now without implementing any redirects on .htaccess file, if I update any content on the site, it is **visible** on the non-www versions of the site **but not** on the www versions. So is there two versions of my website( one https://domainname and the other with https://www )? Also at the my site is hosted on **GoDaddy**. Please suggest because my site is not getting properly indexed and there is also duplicate content issue...